# How can I fix 'gdborig.exe has stopped working' error when debugging on code::blocks?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

I have recently installed Code::Blocks IDE and tried to debug c++ hello world project by choosing Debug->Step into. It opens up the command prompt but gives an error message:

> **gdborig.exe has stopped working**
> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

How do I fix this error?

I'm using code::blocks 20.03 on windows 8.1 with GCC compiler.

Comment: First instance thing to do with any sort of system report is to Google it verbatim, i.e; "_gdborig.exe has stopped working_" there are numerous hits in Code::Blocks specific forums and others including a Code::Blocks specific bug- report: https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/1020/.

Comment: Ensure that the code you have provided does not invoke undefined behavior that might cause the program to stop.

Comment: I can be sure that my program doesn't invoke undefined behaviour. It works correctly when I run it. The problem occurs when debugging it in code blocks. @RohanBari